# LoadLibray function from free pascal fails when run on Linux

Tags: linux, freepascal, .so

I am trying to load a dynamic library `<libname>.so` which is present in current directory as well as in /use/lib, /lib, /lib32. but program is not able to find it to any of these path.

I am running a pascal program and it has this method

```
LibHandle  := LoadLibrary( PAnsiChar(Trim('./libtrdp.so')) );
```

it fails and gives error.

**"This binary has no dynamic library support compiled in.
Recompile the application with a dynamic-library-driver in the program uses clause before other units using dynamic libraries.
Runtime error 235 at $0805F292"**

if anyone is aware of this issue then please let me know as I have searched on the internet but could not find the answer.

Note: I am running this program on Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

Add unit dynlibs to the uses clause.

On Linux, loadlibrary is an empty stub that gets filled when you add dynlibs. This is done to keep the base runtime libc+dl free.